# Resize the uploaded image using php

Tags: php, file-upload, laravel, image-resizing

I need to resize the uploaded image and save it with given resolutions. Assume user uploads just only one single image and I save it like 35x35, 100x100 and 512x512 after finishing the upload. finally his one upload save in my folder as 3 images with different resolutions. I've done up to this point using laravel...

```
public function postSingleUpload()
    {
        //create the relevant directory to add the user image
        //get the directory name (directory name equals to user id)
        $dirPath = sprintf("images/users/avatar/%s/", Auth::user()->id);
        //create the directory named by user id
        if (!file_exists($dirPath)) {
            mkdir($dirPath, 0700);
        }

        $file = Input::file('image');

        //save image with given resulutions
        //---- this part i need --------//
    }
```

so please help me for this.

Comment: http://www.white-hat-web-design.co.uk/blog/resizing-images-with-php/

Comment: I use the package intervention/image. Saves time and works great. Get it at packagist.org.

Answer (score 0):

> Here is what I have done to save the uploaded image with given resolutions:

```
//First Copy the uploaded image to some location
  Input::file('profilePic')->move('Users/'.$username.'/Wallpics/',$name)

  //Set this attribute for quality after resampling
  $quality = 90;
  $src  = 'Users/'.$username.'/Wallpics/'.$name;

  //Run this on recently saved uploaded image
  $img  = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);

  //get this values from user by submitting form ( either by crop or by textboxes)
  $width=(int)Input::get('w');
  $height=(int)Input::get('h');
  $x=(int)Input::get('x');
  $y=(int)Input::get('y');

  //This is the code to resample the image and generate a new to ur requirements

  $dest = ImageCreateTrueColor($width, $height);
  imagecopyresampled($dest, $img, 0, 0,$x,$y, $width, $height,$width,$height);
  imagejpeg($dest, 'Users/'.$username.'/profilePic/'.$name, $quality);

  //Set the path in database 
  $profile->profilePic=asset('Users/'.$username.'/profilePic/'.$name);
  $profile->save();
```